# Listagem de subcategoria conforme categoria selecionada

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while

Tenho o seguinte trecho de codigo:

```
<?php
      foreach($categorias as $cat){
          $id_cat = $cat['id'];
          $subcategorias = array();
          $sqlsub = Comando::Executar("SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE cat_pai = '$id_cat' ");
              while($subarray = $sqlsub->fetch_assoc()){
                   $subcategorias[] = $subarray;
              }
              echo '<select class="btn models '.$cat['nome'].'" name="p_subcategoria" id="p_subcategoria">';
              foreach($subcategorias as $subcat_array){
                  echo '<option value='.$subcat_array['id'].'>'.$subcat_array['nome'].'</option>';
              }
              echo '</select>';
}
?>
```

O array de Subcategorias eh o seguinte :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [nome] => Carnes
            [cat_pai] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [nome] => Massas
            [cat_pai] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [nome] => Sopas
            [cat_pai] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [nome] => Saladas
            [cat_pai] => 3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [nome] => Vinhos
            [cat_pai] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [nome] => Cervejas
            [cat_pai] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [nome] => Sucos
            [cat_pai] => 4
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [nome] => Pudim
            [cat_pai] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [nome] => Doces
            [cat_pai] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [nome] => Geleias
            [cat_pai] => 5
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [nome] => Balas
            [cat_pai] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [nome] => Aperitivos
            [cat_pai] => 6
        )

)
```

Mas sempre que eu vou checar sobre o valor do ID que deveria aparecer no value do OPTION ele retorna a Bala. Primeiro índice do último `array`.

Estou errando na lógica mas ainda não sei onde.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente alterar seu código para:

```
foreach($categorias as $cat){
    $id_cat = $cat['id'];
    $subcategorias = array();
    $sqlsub = Comando::Executar("SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE cat_pai = '$id_cat' ");
    while($subarray = $sqlsub->fetch_assoc()){
        $temp = array(
            'id' => $subarray['id'],
            'nome' => $subarray['nome'],
            'cat_pai' => $subarray['cat_pai'],
        );
        $subcategorias[] = $temp;
    }
    echo '<select class="btn models '.$cat['nome'].'" name="p_subcategoria" id="p_subcategoria">';
    foreach($subcategorias as $subcat_array){
        echo '<option value='.$subcat_array['id'].'>'.$subcat_array['nome'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Imagino que o resultado retornado pelo método `fetch_assoc` é um vetor com valores [passados por referência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php).

Comment: Eai Funcionou ?

Comment: Alexandre muito obrigado pela atenção!
Para esclarecer, a maneira que você me passou é mais organizada de se inserir esses dados no array funcionando perfeito e a maneira com a qual eu estava fazendo também funciona da mesma maneira. Portanto o erro não estava ali. 
Era uma coisa mais idiota e simples.
O primeiro laço ali é um foreach portanto toda vez que ele executava voltava ao inicio e **declarava novamente o ARRAY VAZIO** . Ai estava o meu erro. Por isso ele imprimia o valor de BALA. Ele era o último array sendo criado. Portanto declarar o array fora do código resolveu meu problema. :)

Comment: Se o problema foi resolvido, poste a resposta aqui e assim que possível, marque ele como a resposta.